# How can i make mock testing in my DRF ApiView?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have got a function which make get response to API like that:

```
class Data(APIView):

def get(self, b):
    try:
        user_tokens = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
        user_data = FoundData(user_tokens.refresh_token, request.user)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response('User not found', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except IndexError:
        return Response("Invalid type of authorization",
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except KeyError:
        return Response('Unauthorized, make a authentication again', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

     user_salary_info = Salary.get_data(request.user)
        if user_salary_info is None:
            return Response('Not found', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        money = user_data.count()
        result = {

            'salary': rate * money,
            'rate': rate,
        }
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How will be looks like mock tests for this method?
Please, help